# Access canvas name through button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

My window has more than 50 buttons, and each one has a canvas.

button1 for ex.:

```
                <Button x:Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="98,292,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" Height="115" FontSize="25" Background="Red" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" Click="button1_Click" MouseDown="button1_MouseDown">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.643,1.424" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"><Run Text="1"/></TextBlock>
                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
```

So my question is, how can I get my canvas' name at the button1_Click event?
I want to make a function so i can trigger different canvas'.
For example:

```
void clearCanvas(int canvasNumber)
{
    canvas(+canvasNumber).Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    Canvas canvas = ((StackPanel)btn.Content).Children
                                             .OfType<Canvas>()
                                             .First();
    canvas.Children.Clear();
    //at this point you can also get corresponding `Canvas` name 
    //(if you really have to) :
    //String name = canvas.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it, good to learn an easy way for this.